# how to define an indicator with 2 columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I have these columns

```
           utility     pass
              2          None
              3          NA
              -1         None
             -2           NA
```

indicator is 1 if :  pass=None and utility>0

output

I have these columns

```
           utility     pass          indicator
              2          None            1
              3          NA              0
              -1         None            0
             -2           NA             0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `NA` is an `NA` and not a character, we can achieve the desired output as follows :

With `dplyr`(can use `case_when`):

```
df %>% 
  mutate(indicator = ifelse( !is.na(pass) & utility >0 , 1, 0))
  utility pass indicator
1       2 None         1
2       3 <NA>         0
3      -1 None         0
4      -2 <NA>         0
```

Without relying on external packages, we can do the following with the `base` package:

```
df$indicator <- ifelse( !is.na(df$pass) & df$utility >0 , 1, 0)
```

Using `within`:

```
within(df, {
   indicator <- ifelse(!is.na(pass) & utility >0, 1, 0)
 })
  utility pass indicator
1       2 None         1
2       3 <NA>         0
3      -1 None         0
4      -2 <NA>         0
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(utility = c(2L, 3L, -1L, -2L), pass = structure(c(1L, 
NA, 1L, NA), .Label = "None", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility could be:

```
with(df, +(grepl("None", pass, fixed = TRUE) * utility > 0))

[1] 1 0 0 0
```